# Do we have to collect the tester's testing device UDID to create IPA to upload to Hockeyapp

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, hockeyapp

I have just started using the hockey app, before this,I ask for the tester's device UDID add that to Mobile Provisioning profile, create IPA and give that to the tester, so that he/she could test.

Now After seeing this Hockeyapp, I am interested to use this, my questions is do I have to create IPA by taking UDID from my testers and then upload the app to hockeyapp dashboard to be used by my testers?

Comment: Yes unless you have an enterprise certificate. HockeyApp can automate the collection of the UDID though. Just invite the user to your app.

Comment: I did not understand the point "Hockeyapp" automate the collection of UDID?

Comment: @chedabob do i have to include the Device UDID manually to produce the adhoc provisioning profile and then invite those users?

Comment: You can invite them first. HockeyApp will then collect their UDIDs and place them in a list you can add to the profile.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have an Enterprise account and provisioning, you need to collect your tester's device UDIDs and add them to the provisioning profile you use to build your IPA which you then submit to HockeyApp.
HockeyApp can help you collecting the UDIDs for your testers when they register but any way you need to include them into the build.